# *** No rule to make target, Makefile error in Win10

Tags: windows-10, makefile

First of all, please, don't just tell me this is a duplicate. I know, but the many questions I've looked through have all been given far too specific answers to assist me, and quite frankly half of it went over my head. I'm very new to using Makefiles and I'm baffled by why mine isn't working.

I'm sure it's something painfully simple but please lend a hand, if you need any more information I'll be happy to try to find it, and bear with me because I'm doing all this from my phone because my university's IT department is run by apes. Currently,  this is my Makefile:

## Makefile for Assignment 1

```
finish : main.o 
    g++ -o finish main.o

main.o :    
    g++ -c -g -Wall main.cpp

clean :       
    del main.o
```

(Sorry, it's not being cooperative, I want to make clear that there is the necessary tab in front of the commands)

I'm running this on Windows 10, using a GNU compiler. From what I can see it looks exactly the same as the example Makefile we were provided, aside from filenames. I know I'm in the right directory, nothing is misspelled, the source file should exist cause I'm staring at it sitting next to the makefile. Those are the generic fixes I remember seeing.
The main.o command works perfectly and compiles the source file, but the other two just give me the error

make: *** No rule to make target 'finish/clean'.  Stop.

I'm confused, annoyed, new to Makefiles and Stack Overflow and just looking for a helping hand. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without investigating, an extremely common/confusing error in Makefiles is that they must have tabs, not spaces.

Comment: God man I wish it was that simple, I've got the tabs, it's just that I don't have a good way to put that in on my phone and the text field was being finicky

Comment: it works fine on my machine. Copy paste this [code](https://gist.github.com/TermanEmil/8de1c939f01f82ca6f2f717a43e53a8f) just to make sure. Are you sure you have a main.cpp file in the same directory as the Makefile. I run mingw32-make (perhaps it would help). Try running `make main.o` and see what happenes.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't copy paste the code as my internet is still out, but mine seems to be identical, I even rewrote it a couple times to make sure. I'm absolutely sure the Makefile and the main.cpp are in the same directory. I have a symbolic link (Pretty sure that's the term) to mingw32-make, but I ran it just to check and same result. The weirdest thing is that main.o still works perfectly. Both of the others give me the error but there's not a single problem with the main.o command... Planning to bite the bullet and ask my professor at this rate

Comment: Are you sure that's the makefile Make is using? Try changing the recipe in the `main.o` rule (`g++ -c ...`) into something distinctive (`echo narcissus`) just to verify.

Comment: Beta, you're onto something. Changed the command to echo narcissus like you suggested and it kept trying to compile main.cpp. I deleted the Makefile in the directory and the main.o command still works. What I don't get now is what it could be trying to access, cause I'm for sure using the cmd window in the right directory

Comment: Okay... I think I may have solved the problem my stupid self. I read somewhere that if you highlighted the file path in the File Explorer address bar and typed cmd it would open a command prompt for that directory, sounded convenient so I've been doing that, but now that I put cmd into run and navigated to the directory with cd, problem seems to have gone away... I feel pretty stupid, but thank you all for helping me work through this

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting my example:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g
test.o: test.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c test.cpp
last.o: last.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c last.cpp
program: test.o last.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o program test.o last.o 
clean: 
    $(RM) test.o last.o
```

I was facing similar issue, Try using $(RM) instead of "del"